# Migrating a multi-project Subversion repository to Git with reposurgeon

Tags: git, svn, reposurgeon

I'm trying to convert a Subversion repository to Git using reposurgeon, the repository holds several projects with the following layout:

```
<groupname>/<projectname>/{trunk,tags,branches}
```

I tried this reposurgeon script:

```
read <svnrepository.dump
sourcetype svn
prefer git
rebuild myrepository
```

But the result was a Git repository with a branch per group.

Is there a way to restrict the conversion to a single project?

Answer (score 5):

Use the `--include` option of `svnadmin dump` to restrict the dump to one project, then `repocutter` to strip away the path prefix.

```
svnadmin dump . --include '/<groupname>/<projectname>' | 
    repocutter pathrename '^<groupname>/<projectname>/' '' > svnrepository.dump
```

Then use `reposurgeon` as before.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, unfortunately it didn't work well. `reposurgeon` fails to process the filtered dump, either with a KeyError or a "missing required date field at line".

Comment: Looks like a bug in reposurgeon… wouldn’t be the first. I tried it on one of my own dumped SVN repositories with a similar structure and it did work.